# Assigning colors to Graphics3D objects from an ordered list

Tags: graphics3d

I'd like to draw a set of spheres with colors assigned from a defined set.  To provide an example, say I wish to draw a set of three spheres of radius 2 at the positions: {{6, 5, 10}, {1, 4, 20}, {2, 4, 15}}.  I might write:

```
pos = {{6, 5, 10}, {1, 4, 20}, {2, 4, 15}};
Graphics3D[{Sphere[pos, 2]}]
```

If I define an ordered set of colors for the three spheres, e.g. SphereColors={Red,Blue,Red}, how can I use this list to color the spheres as desired using Graphics3D?

Comment: Then you don't use the *en masse* rendering; you use something like `MapThread[{#1, Sphere[#2, 2]} &, {SphereColors, pos}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do very straightforwadly is:

```
pos = {{6, 5, 10}, {1, 4, 20}, {2, 4, 15}};
Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[pos[[1]], 2], Blue, Sphere[pos[[2]], 2], 
    Green, Sphere[pos[[3]], 2]}]
```

but of course this is somewhat ungeneralizable. So you can make it a bit more general:

```
cols = {Red, Blue, Green};
Graphics3D[Table[{cols[[i]], Sphere[pos[[i]], 2]}, {i, 1, 3}]]
```

[image]

You can also do it in a more elegant manner:

```
Graphics3D[Thread[{cols, Sphere[#, 2] & /@ pos}]]
```

which gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `Thread`, you can also use `MapThread`:

```
pos = {{6, 5, 10}, {1, 4, 20}, {2, 4, 15}};
cols = {Red, Green, Blue};
Graphics3D@MapThread[{#1, Sphere[#2, 2]} &, {cols, pos}]
```

Another way is to use `Apply`

```
Graphics3D[Apply[{#1, Sphere[#2, 2]} &, Transpose[{cols, pos}], {1}]]
```

or using the shorthand notation:

```
Graphics3D[{#1, Sphere[#2, 2]} & @@@ Transpose[{cols, pos}]]
```

Threading twice:

```
Graphics3D[Thread@{cols, Thread@Sphere[pos]}]
```